# Please debug converting string to uri compiler error

Tags: flutter

```
class NetworkHelper {
  NetworkHelper(this.urlToConvert);
  String urlToConvert;
  var url = Uri.parse(urlToConvert);

  //Rest of the code omitted
}
```

Error: Can't access 'this' in a field initializer to read 'urlToConvert'.
var url = Uri.parse(urlToConvert);
^^^^^^^^^^^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to use are `Initializer Lists` in Dart.

```
class NetworkHelper {

    String urlToConvert;
    var url;

    NetworkHelper(this.urlToConvert): url = Uri.parse(urlToConvert);

    //Rest of the code omitted
}
```

Since your `urlToConvert` is only available after the constructor is called, you can't directly initialise other class members that are dependent on your earlier field.